# Upgrade tells me I already have the newest version

Tags: debian, apt, linux-kernel, upgrade

I'm attempting to update `linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64` to `3.2.82` or younger, by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`
```

But it just tells me :

> linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 is already the newest version.

Misc:

`cat /etc/*release` :

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

I'm not sure what might be relevant information, to feel free to ask and I'll provide. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that you are currently using explicitly tells the system to install the latest, strictly-compatible version of the kernel that you're currently running, so it won't switch from the 2.6 kernel you currently have to the 3.2 kernel you want. You might get a newer kernel, but it will usually only include bug and security fixes rather than new features.

Debian has tons of packages each containing a specific version of the kernel.

The `uname -r` command will output the current version of the kernel that you are using, i.e. here `2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`. Hence, the final command will be `sudo apt-get install linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`.

You have two solution. You can either install a metapackage called `xen-linux-system-amd64`, mentionned by Stephen Kitt, that doesn't contain any kernel by itself but always depend on the latest version of the kernel. This solution means that if a new kernel package is released, it will be installed side by side with the previous one. Or you can decide that you specifically want to install `xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64` by using `sudo apt-get install xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64`, in which case you will only have this one version of the kernel installed, and won't ever upgrade to a new version of the kernel (though you might upgrade to a new version of the package).

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install xen-linux-system-amd64` and rebooted. Everything ran without errors, but `uname -r` still says `2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`. I tried Googling but my knowledge here is quite limited. Noticed though that there are now two directories in `/lib/modules`: `2.6.32-5-xen-amd64` and this new one `3.2.0-4-amd64`. Is it using the wrong one? How can i change this?

Comment: This is likely related to your bootloader. The bootloader is a small program that is executed just after the bios/EFI, and that among other things allows the user to choose which of the installed operating systems and kernels they want to use. Most likely your bootloader is `grub`, and the `v2` iteration of it, but there are a few other bootloaders available. Can you check if `grub` is installed? If so you can configure it through editing `/etc/default/grub`, and running the `update-grub` command. See https://wiki.debian.org/Grub#Configuring_GRUB_v2 . Let us know if you need more :).

Comment: The commands `grub` and `update-grub` does not exist, but I were able to locate afew things about the boot. In `/` there are a couple of interesting symlinks:

`vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64` and `vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`

`initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64` and `initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`

Comment: Also there is no `/etc/default/grub` but there is a directory `/boot/grub` with one file: `menu.lst` which contains (among others) these lines:

`title       Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1 (squeeze) amd64, with 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`
`root        (hd0,0)`
`kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 root=/dev/xvda2 ro`
`initrd      /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`

Comment: Note that `/boot` is a symlink to `/mnt/boot/boot`. Thank you for your replies btw!

Comment: Your version of Debian still uses the first version of `grub`, sometimes refered to as `grub legacy`. You can configure it by editing the `menu.lst` file. At the beginning of the file you should have a `timeout X` line, where X is a number. Make sure that number is high enough, as it is the time before `grub` launch the default kernel/OS. Add the following lines at the end of `menu.lst`: `title My new entry`,`root (hd0,0)`, `kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/xvda2 ro` and `initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64`. After rebooting you should be able to choose between entries

Comment: `My new entry`, and the previous `Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1 (squeeze) amd64, with 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`. If booting on `My new entry` works you can set it as the default by editing the first line, which should read `default X` where X is the position of `My new entry` on the list minus one (if `My new entry` is the second entry, put 1, for instance). If it doesn't work, let us know.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img` symlink you mentioned are likely there to allow you to have an entry on Grub that always point to the lastest kernel without editing the menu.lst file each time, as they must be updated to always point toward the latest kernel. Similarly, the `vmlinuz.old` and `initrd.img.old` symlink likely will be updated to point to the second-to-last version of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

To get the latest Xen kernel on Wheezy, you should install [`xen-linux-system-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xen-linux-system-amd64) instead:

```
apt-get install xen-linux-system-amd64
```

This will pull in the 3.2.82 kernel. (It will also ensure you get future kernel updates, within the limits of [Wheezy LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Wheezy).)